# xgboost algorithm is giving excellent auc score on train, validation and test datasets (0.94) but giving worst public score (0.5) after submission

Tags: boosting, auc

I am a beginner in ML modelling. I am working on **Santander Customer Satisfaction Prediction** competition and the evaluation metric is **AUC**. The dataset has 370 features and the target variable is **TARGET** with values 0/1. It dataset has rows around 75K.

I tried logistic regression algorithm which gave me the auc score of 0.76 on train and test sets and 0.74 approx. on submission(test.csv dataset).

I tried Xgboost algorithm to improve the score and built a base model which gave auc score of around 0.94 on training, validation and test datasets. But on submission(test.csv) I'm getting very low score of 0.55 approx. If the model is overfitting then I believe I should get a similar low score on validation and test sets as well. But that is not happening here.

The only feature engineering step I did before splitting the data into val and test sets is counting the no. of zero valued features in a data point. I don't think there is data leakage because of this.

#### Code details:

***adding zeros column:***

```
df.insert(1,'zeros', (df == 0).astype('int64').sum(axis=1))
```

***train, val and test split:***

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features_df, target, train_size=0.75, random_state=100, shuffle=True)
print(x_train.shape, y_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape, y_test.shape)
print('-'*150)
x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, train_size=0.80, random_state=100, shuffle=True)
print(x_train.shape, y_train.shape)
print(x_val.shape, y_val.shape)
```

***Hyperparameters for xgboost algorithm:***

```
xgb_model = XGBClassifier(learning_rate=0.2, n_estimators=37, max_depth=5,
 min_child_weight=2, gamma=0, subsample=0.8, colsample_bytree=0.8,
 objective= 'binary:logistic', nthread=4, scale_pos_weight=1,seed=27)
```

[Kaggle notebook link](https://www.kaggle.com/code/sownikturaga96/santander-prediction-using-xgboost)

Comment: Hello Sownik. You should edit your question to give more details about the problem you're trying to solve (e.g. is it a classification or regression problem? Are time series involved? etc.). It's impossible to answer your question otherwise, and few people will have the time to analyse your code just to understand what you are trying to do, or even register on Kaggle just to know what kind of data you're talking about.

Comment: @J-J-J Thanks for the instructions. Please let me know if any additional details needed.

Comment: It sounds like you’re overfitting to the validation and test sets.

Comment: Hi @Sycorax, can a model overfit on untrained data? If it is possible, what might be the reason? How to handle this?

Comment: Yes, it can happen. It's called overfitting to the validation and test sets. An alternative explanation is that the Kaggle holdout set is drawn from a different distribution than the train/test/validate data you have.

Comment: The question doesn't mention hyperparameter tuning, but that's generally how you would overfit to the validation set. But even then, this seems like too large a performance drop to be reasonably explanained by that. The holdout set being significantly different is promising, if unusual for kaggle. Maybe if you share your notebook something will stand out?

Comment: @BenReiniger Sorry for the late response. I have updated the description with my kaggle notebook link. Please check. Thanks for the response.